# Compiling PhantomJS in Windows (build yourself)

Tags: windows, build, compilation, phantomjs

From the [website of PhantomJS itself](http://phantomjs.org/build.html). The author said:

```
Windows requirements

Supported toolchains: MSVC2012 and MSVC2013.

You must have Perl, Python, Ruby, and Git on PATH. Also, note that Git comes with it’s own version of perl.exe. If you have both Git and a separate perl installation in your PATH, please make sure that you separate Perl install’s bin folder comes before the git’s bin folder in your PATH.

Please also add the folder <phantomjs_path>\src\qt\3rdparty\gnuwin32\bin to your PATH, as required tools such as bison, flex, and gperf will not be found otherwise. Example:

SET PATH=%CD%\src\qt\3rdparty\gnuwin32\bin;%PATH%
Run the build script from Visual Studio Command Prompt.

Tip: Enabling incremental linking will make the linkage process faster.
```

Then I have several questions:

1. Why it is written "**Supported toolchains MSVC2012 & MSVC2013**" instead
   of "**Choose either VS2012 or VS2013**" ? is there any mandatory (a
   must) have install both of the tools? or if I installed just one VS2013, is it enough?
2. Next point is, it's written "**you must have Perl, Python, Ruby, and
   GIT.**" But what is the minimum required version of those tools
   anyway?

Notes: I want to compile & build it under my Windows 7x64.

Comment: So were use able to build PhantomJS? if yes, how? (You never got back to this question)

Comment: already solved. take a look at the bottom's answer @Vaviloff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSVC2013 is enough.
Current versions of Perl, Python, Ruby, and GIT are ok.
Last time I've successfully built it on Windows 7 x64 in winter 2016 with

- ActiveState Perl v5.20.2
- Python 2.7.5
- ruby 1.9.3p545
- git version 1.9.4.msysgit.1